# grouping relationships of many-to-many-to many

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a requirement to map a tax rate to a person based on the country the person was resident at that time.

```
tbl: person
| p_id | name_first | name_last |
=======++========================
| 1    | john       | smith     |
| 2    | joanne     | smyth     |


            tbl: person_in_country
            | p_id | iso | arrived    |
            ===========================
            | 1    | GB  | 1980-01-01 |
            | 2    | FR  | 1987-03-21 |
            | 1    | FR  | 2003-06-17 |
            | 1    | JP  | 2008-07-02 |
            | 2    | GB  | 2008-10-01 |
            | 1    | GB  | 2009-01-10 |

tbl: country
| iso | ctry_name      |
========================
| GB  | United Kingdom |
| FR  | France         |
| JP  | Japan          |

            tbl: tax_rates
            | iso | tax_rate | tax_date   |
            ===============================
            | GB  | 17.5     | 1970-01-01 |
            | FR  | 15.0     | 1977-03-21 |
            | JP  | 12.0     | 1977-06-17 |
            | FR  | 15.0     | 1994-03-21 |
            | JP  | 18.5     | 2008-07-02 |
            | GB  | 15       | 2008-04-01 |
            | GB  | 20       | 2010-05-01 |
```

So I need tuples containing the person in the country and the tax rate that they should have at a given time..

Something along the lines of:

```
select p.p_id, p.name_first, p.name_last,
       pic.arrived,
       c.iso, c.ctry_name,
       t.tax_rate
from people p
left join (select * from person_in_country order by arrived desc) pic using (p_id)
left join country c on c.iso = pic.iso
left join (select * from tax_rates order by tax_date desc) t on t.iso = c.iso
where t.tax_date <= NOW()
group by p.pid, pic.arrived, t.tax_date
```

Hope this make sense... and many thanks in advance

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you have to do a query basicly in three steps. First one you are going to retrieve a kind of "raw data" with all desired columns, joining the relating tables,  whatever these columns will be used to join or to retrieve choosen data.

After that, you have to group data in order to turn only last dates from the matching join.

Finally, you have to query again tax table to retrieve tax in the tax date current at the moment of arrival.

It is possible that there is a more easy or ellegant way to do so, but this query is working. Check your system performance depending on the query demmands. It seems a bit hard at a first glance, but it isn't when taking a more carefull look. The SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    c02.iso, 
    c02.p_id, 
    c02.name_first, 
    c02.name_last, 
    c02.ctry_name, 
    c02.arrived, 
    c02.mtax_date, 
    tax_rates.tax_rate

FROM (
    SELECT 
        c01.iso, 
        c01.p_id, 
        c01.name_first, 
        c01.name_last, 
        c01.ctry_name, 
        c01.arrived, 
        Max(c01.tax_date) AS mtax_date
    FROM (

        SELECT 
            country.iso, 
            person.p_id, 
            person.name_first, 
            person.name_last, 
            country.ctry_name, 
            person_in_country.arrived, 
            tax_rates.tax_date
        FROM 
            tax_rates 
        INNER JOIN (
                country 
        INNER JOIN (
                person 
        INNER JOIN 
                person_in_country 
            ON 
                person.p_id = person_in_country.p_id
               )
            ON 
                country.iso = person_in_country.iso
               ) 
            ON 
                tax_rates.iso = person_in_country.iso
            GROUP BY 
                country.iso, 
                person.p_id, 
                person.name_first, 
                person.name_last, 
                country.ctry_name, 
                person_in_country.arrived, 
                tax_rates.tax_date
            HAVING (((tax_rates.tax_date)<=[arrived]))
        ) as c01
    GROUP BY 
        c01.iso, 
        c01.p_id, 
        c01.name_first, 
        c01.name_last, 
        c01.ctry_name, 
        c01.arrived
    ) as c02 

INNER JOIN 
    tax_rates ON (
            c02.mtax_date = tax_rates.tax_date
             ) 
             AND 
             (
            c02.iso = tax_rates.iso
              );
```

Output:

```
iso p_id    name_first  name_last   ctry_name   arrived     mtax_date   tax_rate
GB  1   john        smith       United Kindom   01/01/1980  01/01/1970  18
FR  2   joanne      smyth       France          21/03/1987  21/03/1977  15
FR  1   john        smith       France          17/06/2003  21/03/1994  15
JP  1   john        smith       Japan           02/07/2008  02/07/2008  18
GB  1   john        smith       United Kindom   10/01/2009  01/04/2008  15
GB  2   joanne      smyth       United Kindom   01/10/2008  01/04/2008  15
```

Comment: One more tip: SQL is also a language, try to be as much indentfull as you can! ;)